# how to make file upload mandatory yii

Tags: file, file-upload, yii, validation

im a bit new to this, 
I have a model with an attribute file_id but it'll be displayed as File. I should make this mandatory..but when user uploads a file, I'm storing the file path and all in file table. and getting id from that table and storing it in my model.

can anyone pls tell me how can i make  **file upload mandatory for create but not for update**

my code for file upload is:

```
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'file');?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'file'); ?>`
```

its working fine. but i need to make it mandatory for this current model. do i need to make it required in rules function in file model or current model??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be in the model rules:

```
array('file', 'required','on'=>'insert'),
```

Then it is only required on insert and not updates.

Another way would be to utilize the before or afterValidate method:

```
protected function afterValidate(){
    if($this->isNewRecord){
        if(!isset($this->file)){ //Not sure about handling files if this works.
            $this->addError("file","Not file selected.  Please choose a file to upload.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return parent::afterValidate();
}
```

Comment: im storing this file in other model(Table) but getting its id and storing file id in my model

Comment: the problem is, if i dont use required its working fine. if i use this : array('file', 'required','on'=>'insert'), or array('file', 'required') its again saying file cant be blank(no matter even i upload the file) :(

Comment: try `'create'` instead of insert.  I think that is the right context.

Comment: thats correct..but not working though :(  asterick(*) required  mark is not coming for file field if i'm doing so..actually i need to get file_id for my model(file_id is the attribute for my model). this file id would be id of the file i'm storing for it

Comment: The line array('file', 'required','on'=>'insert'), worked for me. +1